# What can be the reason for "non-initialised socket" & "can't resolve host name" error for ookla speedtest-cli tool?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, openvpn

I installed the speed test-clip tool by Ookla that was working fine last evening, but since this morning, I have been trying and it isn't working. And I get the error as shown below? What can be the reason? Oh, and I installed OpenVPN and some ca-certificates related to it. Does it have anything to do with this issue?

I am on **Debian 11.3**.

```bsh
$ speedtest
[2022-04-27 01:00:12.341] [error] Trying to get interface information on non-initialized socket.
[2022-04-27 01:00:17.349] [error] Configuration - Couldn't resolve host name (HostNotFoundException)
[2022-04-27 01:00:17.349] [error] Configuration - Cannot retrieve configuration document (0)
[2022-04-27 01:00:17.349] [error] ConfigurationError - Could not retrieve or read configuration (Configuration)
[2022-04-27 01:00:17.349] [error] ConfigurationError - Could not retrieve or read configuration (Configuration)
[error] Configuration - Could not retrieve or read configuration (ConfigurationError)
```